# Use hyphen in mysql table name

Tags: mysql

I try to do:

```
select * from 'foo-bar';
```

in the mysql CLI but I get a syntax error near ''foo-bar''.
I guess that is due to the hyphen in the table name.

How can i resolve that issue?

Comment: it does neither work with single nor mit double quotes

Comment: That's because both of those options are incorrect.  Please refer to the linked duplicate.

Comment: Oh it works with backticks, thanks I haven't known that.